# Add an item to cart with Python requests

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to add an item to the cart. I am fairly new to coding in python so I have tried to make some kind of code that will do it for me. But the code is not adding the item to the cart, and there is no errors when starting the code. So I want to hear if someone out there could help me fix this problem?

The item im trying to add in to the cart: [here](https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html)

My code:

```
from urllib import response
import requests, re, json

session = requests.session()
ProductSize = 44

def get_color_results(link):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
    data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"enrichedEntity".*size.*)<\/script', r).group(1))
    results = []
    color = ""
    for i in data["graphqlCache"]:
        if "ern:product" in i:
            if "product" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]:
                if "name" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]:
                    results.append(data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"])
                if (
                    color == ""
                    and "color" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]
                ):
                    color = data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]["color"]["name"]
    return (color, results)


link = "https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html"
final = {}
color, results = get_color_results(link)
colors = {
    j["node"]["color"]["name"]: j["node"]["uri"]
    for j in [
        a
        for b in [
            i["family"]["products"]["edges"]
            for i in results
            if "family" in i
            if "products" in i["family"]
        ]
        for a in b
    ]
}
final[color] = {
    j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
    for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
}

for k, v in colors.items():
    if k not in final:
        color, results = get_color_results(v)
        final[color] = {
            j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
            for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
        }



def cart():
    global session

    response = "https://www.zalando.dk/api/graphql/add-to-cart/"
    payload = "https://www.zalando.dk/api/rr/e"


    if '"cartActionProductSize":"%s"'%(ProductSize) in payload.text and '"addToCart":' in response.text:
        session.post(payload)
        print("Added to cart")

    elif '"addToCart":null' in response.text:
        cart()
        print("Something went wrong")
```

**UPDATE**

Hey, I have updated the post because some coding errors and I have made it so that is easier to understand.

Comment: Are you sure that add_to_cart is the GET functionality?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ I'm not 100% sure, but something tells me it is.  As I said in the question, this is just an example of how I would like it and would have liked to have made it actually work.

Comment: change `if "color" = (color_chosen) and "size" = (size_chosen) and stock = 'MANY'
` to ---->  `if "color" == (color_chosen) and "size" == (size_chosen) and stock == 'MANY'
`

Comment: Thanks @PrestigeDev, it fixed an error but it does not add anything to the cart

Comment: You also need to change "color" to color.

Comment: @PrestigeDev Yea, but its still not adding to the cart

Comment: Hey @PrestigeDev, what you can see is an **example** and not the code I wanted to work. I was really just asking if there were any that could help me make so it adds a certain size and a certain color to my cart. I hope you understand or I will try to explain it in a different way